# iOS MediaPlayer Seeking

Tags: ios, media-player, seek

I am able to use iOS MediaPlayer and play a movie by this way. But I need, seeking a sec of a movie. How can I do this, I play a movie by MediaPlayer like that:

```
    NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:self.filename];

    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) 
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
                                               object:moviePlayer];

    moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone; 
    moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES; 
    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view]; 
    [moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: I figured out this problem. it may help to other developers, moviePlayer.initialPlaybackTime = 5;   then mediaplayer starts from 5.sec of the movie .

Comment: Can you write the solution in as the answer and mark it as the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for own answer,

```
NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:self.filename];

MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) 
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
                                           object:moviePlayer];

moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone; 
moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES; 
moviePlayer.initialPlaybackTime = 5;
[self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view]; 
[moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
```

this worked for me in order to seek a time in a movie...